# Sending G-code commands to Hyrel System 30M using python

Tags: g-code, usb, serial-connection, python

I am using python 3.6 with pySerial library to connect to the Hyrel System 30M 3D Printer. I am able to read the data from the device but unable to write any commands to it

Here is the code:

```
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.port = 'COM4'
    ser.baudrate = 38400
    out = ser.readline()
    ser.write(b'M106 T14 S30\n') %This is the command to turn on the fan at 30% power
```

Can somebody suggest me how to write commands to printer through python

Answer (score 2):

If the one in your question is your *complete* code, a possibility is that your computer is just buffering the output for the serial port, withholding it in memory.  Try to add

```
ser.flush()
```

after your last line.  This command will... well... *flush* anything into the buffer through the actual connection.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer, but with Repetrel v3 and later, we have the option for you to configure a secondary COM port, and relay G- or M-Code commands from your other source through the Repetrel software to the printer. Please contact us for assistance.

Note: I work for Hyrel 3D.